# Huge chunks of minified js file interpretted as block comments

Tags: javascript, angularjs, intellij-idea, block-comments, minifiedjs

I didn't see almost any support on this issue surprisingly (I'd imagine this to be a common problem) so, I'm here.

I'm working on an angularFire webapp and when downloading the minified js files for the latest versions of angular (1.5.0) and firebase (3.0.3) and opening them in my IDE (IntelliJ) I noticed that huge portions of the code were being interpreted as block comments following the block comment notation "/*".

I've attached some pictures showing this:

[image: angular]

[image: firebase]

Placing a backslash right before the asterisk seems to fix the problem, but I'm unsure if it's being interpreted properly as an escape character or not. Should I be worried about this? Wouldn't developers check for something like this?

Comment: This is presumably a bug in the syntax highlighting in IntelliJ. Report it to them.

Comment: Is this just your hunch or you've seen this problem before?

Comment: Are those my only two options? :-) There are two possibilities: 1) Angular's minified JavaScript is completely broken, but no one noticed until you. 2) There's a bug in IntelliJ's syntax highlighting. I took an educated guess.

Comment: I checked with jQuery's min file and the same thing happens in the presence of multiple forward/backslashes so, yes, it does appear to be a bug in IntelliJ's syntax highlighting...all of which no one noticed until me ;)